# Alamofire: handle error with success response

Tags: json, swift, alamofire

Hi i am still new to Alamofire and json. i just want to ask on how to handle error on success response. Below is the response of the api with post request.

```
{
data =     {
    "cabinet_id" = 3289146811;
    "created_at" = "2018-04-11T04:53:43.288023001Z";
    "user_id" = 123abc;
};
}
```

but sometimes i got response as below due to server error

```
{
error =     {
    "http_status_code" = 400;
    message = "Unable to proceed";
    type = "rent_request_failed";
};
}
```

here is what i have did

```
let url = "myurl"
let parameters = ["user_id": ""\(self.idPassed)"",
                          "cabinet_id": "\(self.stringPassed)"]

        Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: URLEncoding.default).responseJSON { response in

                if (response.result.isSuccess){

                    if let value = response.result.value {
//now success or failed always navigate to here                            
Helper.helper.switchToNavigationViewController(Navigation: "hundredpercent")
                        print(value)

                    }
                //do your json stuff
                } else if (response.result.isFailure) {
                //Manager your error
                switch (response.error!._code){
                case NSURLErrorTimedOut:
                //Manager your time out error
                break
                case NSURLErrorNotConnectedToInternet:
                //Manager your not connected to internet error
                break
                default:
                    let alertt = UIAlertController(title: "Server Error!", message: "Please try again", preferredStyle: .alert)

                    alertt.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: {(action:UIAlertAction!) in
//need navigate here if error                        
Helper.helper.switchToNavigationViewController(Navigation: "qrcodescan")

                    }))

                    self.present(alertt, animated: true)
                }
                }
        }
```

Comment: You can validate the status code from request itself. Rather than just request do `req.validate(statusCode: 200..<299).responseJSON(completionHandler: { response in` It will take your status codes `200-299` in success and rest in failure

Comment: tq @AnkitJayaswal its work...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Validate the response status code while calling API by adding `validate(statusCode: 200..<299)` on alamofire request.

It will validate to success if your http status code lies in interval `200-299` otherwise it go into failure case.

```
        // Call response handler method of alamofire
        Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: URLEncoding.default).validate(statusCode: 200..<299).responseJSON(completionHandler: { response in

            switch response.result {
            case .success(let data): 
                Logs.DLog(object: "\n Success: \(response)")

                // Do your code here...

            case .failure(let error):
                Logs.DLog(object: "\n Failure: \(error.localizedDescription)")

                // Do your code here...

            }
        })
```

Comment: FYI by default, acceptable range of 200...299 so you dont have to specify that

Answer (score 2):

This is a way that I used handle the  responce. Hope this will help you.

```
class func Request(statusCallBack: @escaping (_ statusCode: Int) -> Void, successCallback: @escaping (_ result: AnyObject) -> Void, errorCallback: @escaping (_ error: Error) -> Void) {

Alamofire.request(url, method: method, parameters: params, encoding: encodingType, headers: headers).responseJSON { (responce) in

        // Here checking the status code of response
        if let status = responce.response?.statusCode {
            if status == 401 && AppUserDefault.getAccessToken() != nil {
                User.logout()
                return
            }
            statusCallBack(status)
        }
        switch responce.result {
        case .success(_):
            if let result = responce.result.value {
                successCallback(result as AnyObject)
            } else {
                errorCallback(NSError(domain: "Internal server error", code: 1002, userInfo: nil))
            }
            break
        case .failure(let error) :
            errorCallback(error)
            break
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: if you Validate the response status code while calling API by adding validate() on alamofire request then you can have         // Here checking the status code of response
        `if let status = responce.response?.statusCode {
            if status == 401 && AppUserDefault.getAccessToken() != nil {
                User.logout()
                return
            }
            statusCallBack(status)
        }` 
in  `case .failure(let error) :`

Answer (score 0):

Use [SwiftyJSON](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON) and try like this

```
  switch response.result {
  case .success:
    if let value = response.result.value {
      let json = JSON(value)
      if ( response.response!.statusCode == 200 || response.response!.statusCode == 201) {
        let localStatusCode = json["status"].intValue

        if localStatusCode >= 400 {
          if json["errors"] != JSON.null{
            callback(json["errors"].stringValue, nil)
          }else{
              callback(json["message"].stringValue, nil)
          }
        }else {
          callback(nil, json)
        }
      }else if response.response?.statusCode != 200 {
        callback(json["error"].stringValue, nil)
      }
    }
  case .failure(let error):

    NSLog("Failure \(error),\(urlString)")

    if(response.response?.statusCode == 401){

    }
    if  let errorStr = response.data {
      let errorJson = JSON(errorStr)
      if(errorJson != JSON.null){
        if errorJson["error"] != JSON.null{
          callback(errorJson["error"].stringValue, nil)
        }else{
          callback(errorJson["message"].stringValue, nil)
        }
      }else {
        callback(error.localizedDescription,nil)
      }
    }else {
      callback("Error Connecting to Server", nil)
    }
  }
})
```