# Alamofire Value of type 'Result<Any, AFError>' has no member 'isSuccess' (Swift 5)

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I have a simple procedure, which I used in my earlier version (*Swift 4*). I have now updated to the new version (*Swift 5, Alamofire 5.0.0-rc.2*), as I am still beginner I got problems with this. Some code parts I could already rewrite.

```
let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
        "SubscriptionKey": SubscriptionKey,
        "Host": HostName
    ]

    AF.request(URL(string: userInfoUrl)!, method: .get, parameters: nil, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers)
        .validate()
        .responseJSON { response in
            guard response.result.isSuccess else {
                log.error("Error requesting user ID: \(String(describing: response.result.error))")
                completion(false, nil)
                return
            }

            guard let json = response.result.value as? [String: Any], let userId = json["userId"] as? String else {
                log.error("Malformed result from API call.")
                completion(false, nil)
                return
            }
```

**response.result.isSuccess** is not possible. How can I reuse this part?

Error: Value of type 'Result' has no member 'isSuccess'

As a possible solution, I will test the above solution.

```
AF.request(URL(string: userInfoUrl)!, method: .get, parameters: nil, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers)
    .validate()
    .responseJSON { response in
        switch response.result{
        case .success(let value):
            //succcess, do anything

        case .failure(let error):
            log.error("Error requesting user ID: \(String(describing: response.error))")
            completion(false, nil)
            return
        }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Alamofire: handle error with success response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49767008/alamofire-handle-error-with-success-response)

Answer (score 8):

Result is containing `.success` or `.failure` case.

So you should treat `isSuccess` like this

```
switch response.result {
   case .success(let value):
//success, do anything
   case .failure(let error): 
//failure
}
```

Comment: Thank you for hinting. I already tried this way, but I can't define my Success Case. See in my code via **guard response.result.isSuccess**

Comment: success case is literally a  `case .success`. If you want it, like you have, it should be `guard try? response.result.get() != nil else { return }` . Just to clarify: you're using Alamofire 5.0.0 **rc**, which now support Swift 5 `Result` type, so older documentation references are wrong. You can look on swift result type here https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/result

Comment: How do people know to do this when upgrading from AlamoFire 4 to AlamoFire 5? Is it just because the AlamoFire docs assume that everyone has read https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/result , and the people coming in with these correct answers have read that specific Apple documentation page?

Comment: @AndrewKoster due to major releases Alamofire publish docs for migration. Alamofire team do great job, but managing dependencies are developers' responsibility. Don't blame opensource, they doing their best to enhance your experience and evolving their "product" further  https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/Alamofire%205.0%20Migration%20Guide.md

Comment: @IliyaKisliy But that's my point, the Alamofire project doesn't publish migration docs that address this issue, at least not anywhere that I can find. So how do people know how to fix this unavoidable dependency issue that will break your code 100% of the time that you upgrade to this version of Alamofire? Is there a secret Alamofire migration docs site that I don't know about?

Comment: @IliyaKisliy The documentation page that you linked says only this about the issue: "Result has been removed. Alamofire now uses Swift’s Result type." That's almost useless. Your answer is much more useful because it actually shows me an example of how to use their new API. They know how to use their own new API, they should include a code example.